# What is the source of the narration of Uthman ibn Affan letting his slave tweak his ear in retaliation, and is it authentic?

Tags: hadith, history, source-identification

> روى أن عثمان بن عفان رضي الله عنه دَعَك أُذُن عَبْدٍ له على ذنب فعله ، ثم قال له بعد ذلك : تقدم واقرص أذني ، فامتنع العبد فألح عليه ، فبدأ يقرص بخفة ، فقال له : اقرص جيداً ، فإني لا أتحمل عذاب يوم القيامة ، فقال العبد : وكذلك يا سيدي : اليوم الذي تخشاه أنا أخشاه أيضاً
>
> It was narrated that [‘Uthmaan ibn ‘Affaan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uthman) tweaked the ear of a slave of his when he did something wrong, then he said to him after that: Come and tweak my ear in retaliation. The slave refused but he insisted, so he started to tweak it slightly, and he said to him: Do it strongly, for I cannot bear the punishment on the Day of Resurrection. The slave said: Like that, O my master? The Day that you fear I fear also. ([Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/94840))

Can you tell me this source of this story and if it is authentic narration?

Comment: This is an interesting Question I've only found the same quotes of this fatwa everywhere without any link to a source!

Comment: @Medi1Saif [relevant](http://alifta.net/Fatawa/FatawaChapters.aspx?languagename=ar&View=Page&PageID=4533&PageNo=1&BookID=2&TableName=Abhas&ID=566&NextTocID=566) and [relevant](http://ibnhomaid.af.org.sa/sites/default/files/talbees.pdf) but as you say, even there i find no sources!

Answer (score 2):

**Asalaam Alaikum**

this event is mentioned in the books of islamic history. there is a slight difference in the wordings but it's just only due to the preference of the translator i believe.

---

**EXCERPT FROM SOURCE**

> Ibn Shabbah narrated with his isnad that Uthman ibn Affan entered upon a slave of his who was feeding his she-camel, and he saw something in the feed that he disliked, so he took hold of the slave’s ear and tweaked it. Then he regretted it and said to his slave: Settle the score. The slave refused, but he did not leave him alone until he had taken hold of his ear and begun to tweak it. Uthman said to him: Pull hard, until he thought that (the slave) had pulled as hard as he had done. Then Uthman [R.A] said: **How easy it is to settle a score before it is settled in the Hereafter after.**

- *[[Tareekh al-Madinah also known as Umara' al-Madinah](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13086/2042#p1) by Ibn Shabbah, 3/236]*

**TAKEN FROM :** The Biography of Uthman ibn Affan Dhun-Noorayn, page-157

---

may Allah the mighty and sublime grant us mercy and guide us to the straight path.

**ALLAH KNOWS BEST**